# Login con vu.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

** estoy empezando con este framework y tengo un problema, quiero colocar la palabra Mostrar en lugar del icono del Ojo **

```
<v-text-field prepend-inner-icon='mdi-lock'
              v-model="userInfo.password"
              label="Contraseña"
              :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
              :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
              @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
              counter=true
              :rules="txtUserPassword"
              />
```

[image: LOGIN]

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta realizar lo siguiente:

```
<v-text-field prepend-inner-icon='mdi-lock'
          v-model="userInfo.password"
          label="Contraseña"
          :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
         
          counter=true
          :rules="txtUserPassword"
          >
    <template v-slot:append>

      <p  @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword" >Mostrar</p>

    </template>

</v-text-field>
```

Recuerda que puedes insertar HTML en los componentes de VUETIFY